# Proof that for $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$, hold that $\left |\sqrt {a^2+b^2}-\sqrt {a^2+c^2} \right |\leq \left |b-c \right |$.

Tags: real-analysis

Proof that for $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$, hold that $\left |\sqrt {a^2+b^2}-\sqrt {a^2+c^2}  \right |\leq \left |b-c  \right |$.
Give me a clue, I don't have any idea to work with that inequality.

Comment: Nothing bad will happen if you upvote from time to time the answers you get. I see that you have 18 questions asked with a lot of answers on them and only a single upvote...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\left|\sqrt {a^2+b^2} - \sqrt {a^2+c^2}\right| =\frac{\lvert b^2-c^2\rvert}{\left|\sqrt {a^2+b^2} + \sqrt {a^2+c^2}\right|}
= \big||b| - |c|\big|\cdot \frac{|b| + |c|}{\left|\sqrt {a^2+b^2} + \sqrt {a^2+c^2}\right|}
 \\\leq \big||b| - |c|\big|\le |b-c|
$$

Answer (score 0):

Apply the Mean value theorem to the function $f(x)=\sqrt{a^2+x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the points with coordinates $A(0,a),B(b,0),C(c,0)$.

You are stating that the sides of $ABC$ fulfill the triangular inequality.