# $|{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-\sqrt{a^2+c^2}}|\le|b-c|$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Show that $|{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-\sqrt{a^2+c^2}}|\le|b-c|$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$

I'd like to get an hint on how to get started. What I thought to do so far is dividing to cases to get rid of the absolute value. $(++, +-, -+, --)$
but it looks messy. I'm wondering if there is any nicer way to solve it.

Would love to hear some ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would square the whole thing.

Comment: It seems that you can assume without loss of generality that $b\geq c$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof that for $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$, hold that $\left |\sqrt {a^2+b^2}-\sqrt {a^2+c^2} \right |\leq \left |b-c \right |$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677047/proof-that-for-a-b-c-in-mathbbr-hold-that-left-sqrt-a2b2-sqrt-a) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7C%7B%5Csqrt%7Ba%5E2%2Bb%5E2%7D-%5Csqrt%7Ba%5E2%2Bc%5E2%7D%7D%7C%5Cle%7Cb-c%7C%24&p=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the formula: $${\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}}= {x-y\over \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}$$

in your case you get:

$${\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-\sqrt{a^2+c^2}}= {a^2+b^2-(a^2+c^2)\over \sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{a^2+c^2}}$$

so you have to prove (if you assume $b\geq c$, which you can): $$b+c\leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{a^2+c^2}$$

and this is trivaly...

Answer (score 2):

It will be easy if you think $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ as the euclidean distance. Consider the three points $A(a, 0), B(0, b), C(0, c)$. Then the inequality can be transformed into the triangular inequality $\lvert \overline{AB} - \overline{AC} \rvert \le \overline{BC}$

Answer (score 0):

For all $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
0 &\leq (b-c)^2\\
2bc &\leq b^2 + c^2\\
2a^2bc &\leq a^2b^2 + a^2c^2\\
a^4 + 2a^2bc + b^2c^2 &\leq a^4 + a^2b^2 + a^2c^2 + b^2c^2\\
a^2 + bc&\leq \sqrt{a^4 + a^2b^2 + a^2c^2 + b^2c^2} \label{1}\tag{1}\\
2a^2 + 2bc&\leq 2\sqrt{a^4 + a^2b^2 + a^2c^2 + b^2c^2}\\
2a^2 -2\sqrt{a^4 + a^2b^2 + a^2c^2 + b^2c^2}&\leq -2bc\\
2a^2 +b^2 + c^2 -2\sqrt{a^4 + a^2b^2 + a^2c^2 + b^2c^2}&\leq b^2 -2bc + c^2\\
(a^2 +b^2) -2\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(a^2+c^2)} + (a^2 + c^2)&\leq b^2 -2bc + c^2\\
\end{align}

and then take the square root of both sides.

Note that it was not necessary to use absolute values the first time we took a square root $(\ref{1})$ because the right hand side is understood to be positive.

[image]